# Alternative to peek in Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream, side-effects

There are lots of questions regarding `peek` in the Java Streams API. I'm looking for a way to complete the following common pattern using Java Streams. I can make it work with Streams, but it is non-obvious which means slightly dangerous without a comment which it is not ideal.

```java
boolean anyPricingComponentsChanged = false;
for (var pc : plan.getPricingComponents()) {
    if (pc.getValidTill() == null || pc.getValidTill().compareTo(dateNow) <= 0) {
        anyPricingComponentsChanged = true;
        pc.setValidTill(dateNow);
    }
}
```

My option:

```java
long numberChanged = plan.getPricingComponents()
    .stream()
    .filter(pc -> pc.getValidTill() == null || pc.getValidTill().compareTo(dateNow) <= 0)
    .peek(pc -> pc.setValidTill(dateNow))
    .count(); //`count` rather than `findAny` to ensure that `peek` processes all components.

boolean anyPricingComponentsChanged = numberChanged != 0;
```

As an aside, whilst `compareTo` is not an expensive operation here and consistently returns the same result, in other cases this might not be true, and I'd rather avoid running it multiple times for this pattern.

Comment: I think fundamentally any intentional side-effect inside of a stream will have the same problem of being non-obvious and easy to get wrong. I think your solution is reasonable with the caveats you gave. I don't think there's a way to fundamentally change the fact that side-effects are unintuitive/unexpected in streams.

Comment: Not everything should be implemented with streams…

Comment: @DidierL yes I think this is the correct answer. For my simple case there's no savings in terms of lines of code, or in simplicity of understanding which is why I normally use Streams.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> // to ensure that `peek` processes all components

You can't really ensure that `peek()` would process all the stream elements that should be modified. In some cases, this operation can be elided from the pipeline, and you should not perform any important actions via `peek()`.

Here's a quote from the [documenation of `peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)):

> **API Note:**
>
> This method exists mainly to **support debugging**, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline ...
>
> In cases where the **stream implementation is able to optimize away the production of some or all the elements** (such as with short-circuiting operations like findFirst, or in the example described in count()), the action will not be invoked for those elements.

Also, here's what [Stream API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects) says regarding *Side-effects*:

> If the behavioral parameters do have side-effects, unless explicitly stated, there are no guarantees as to:
>
> - the visibility of those side-effects to other threads;
> - that different operations on the "same" element within the same stream pipeline are executed in the same thread; and
> - that behavioral parameters are always invoked, since a stream implementation is free to elide operations (or entire stages) from a
>   stream pipeline if it can prove that it would not affect the result of
>   the computation.
>
> ...
>
> The eliding of side-effects may also be surprising. With the exception
> of terminal operations `forEach` and `forEachOrdered`, **side-effects of
> behavioral parameters may not always be executed when the stream
> implementation can optimize away** the execution of behavioral
> parameters without affecting the result of the computation. (For a
> specific example see the API note documented on the count operation.)

<sup>Amphesys added</sup>

Since `peek` is not meant to contribute to the result of the stream execution Stream implementations are free to throw it away.

Instead of relying on `peek()` you can do the following:

```
List<PricingComponent> componentsToChange = plan.getPricingComponents()
    .stream()
    .filter(pc -> pc.getValidTill() == null || pc.getValidTill().compareTo(dateNow) <= 0)
    .toList();
    
componentsToChange.forEach(pc -> pc.setValidTill(dateNow));

boolean anyPricingComponentsChanged = componentsToChange.size() != 0;
```

If you don't want to materialize the objects that need to be modified as a List, then stick with a `for`-loop.

#### Note

- The quotes above from the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects) like *"stream implementation is free to elide operations (or entire stages) from a stream pipeline if it can prove that it would not affect the result of the computation"* are applicable to **any intermediate operation** having an embedded side-effect. Either a side-effect can be elided, or the whole pipeline stage (stream operation) optimized away if it has no impact on the result. And to be on the same page regurding the terminology, in short, *side-effect* - is anything that a function does apart from producing the required result (*e.g. `i -> { side-effect; return i * 2; }`*)
- Although it's not advisable to assign `peek()` with an action which should be executed at any circumstances, at least is choice doesn't contradicts the semantics of `peek`. To the contrary, performing side-effects via `filter`, `map`, or other operation which are not designed to operate through side-effects not only **doesn't resolve** the problem, but is also weird since it goes against the semantics of these operations and violates the [*Principle of least astonishment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: tricky question: is it safe to replace `peek` by `map` in particular TC case? IMO, javadoc fails to shed a light on that.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov You mean `map(pc -> { pc.setValidTill(dateNow); return pc; }`? API documentation says *"stream implementation is free to elide operations (or entire stages) from a stream pipeline if it can prove that it would **not affect the result of the computation**"*. Therefore, it's not guaranteed that implementation would not optimize away such `map` operation because it has no impact on the result (basically it's `map(Function.identity()`). Also, `map` is not meant to perform side-effects.

Comment: yep, at first glance it is clear that "typically" `map` does not affect result of `count`, however "special note" exists for `peek` operation, from my perspective the problematic operation is actually `count` but not `peek`, moreover, I wonder how implementation may prove that previous operation does not affect result of the computation if any operation may throw runtime exception.

Comment: *"problematic operation is actually `count`*" - `count()` is only one example of such optimization. There are cases apart from it where `peek` or **any other** *intermediate operation* which doesn't affect the result of the stream execution can be optimized away.

Comment: Does that actually mean smth. like `.map(__ -> 1).reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0)` could potentially trigger such "optimizations" as well (besides that reviewer might "optimize" it manually)? Doesn't such behaviour make the idea of using stream api unusable in case when we would like to somehow process data but the only thing we are interested in is the amount of data processed?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov all that matters, is the *terminal operation*. The terminal operation tells the Stream, what kind of result you are interested in. Any other “result” created outside the terminal operation as a side effect, is unreliable. If your terminal operation is `.reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0)`, any optimization that still produces the correct sum is valid.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I think your point "stick with a for-loop." is basically the correct answer. For my simple case there's no savings in terms of lines of code, or in simplicity of understanding which is why I normally use Streams.